# Tracking loss and embeddings in Gensim word2vec model

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I'm pretty new to Gensim and I'm trying to train my first model using word2vec model. I see that all the parameters are pretty straightforward and easy to understand, however I don't know how to track the loss of the model to see the progress. Also, I would like to be able to get the embeddings after each epoch so that I can also *show* that the predictions also get more *logical* with after each epoch. How can I do that?

OR, is it better to train for *iter=1* each time and save the loss and embeddings after each epoch? Sounds not too efficient.

Not much to show with the code but still posting it below:

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences = trainset, 
             iter = 5, # epoch
             min_count = 10, 
             size = 150, 
             workers = 4, 
             sg = 1, 
             hs = 1, 
             negative = 0, 
             window = 9999)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`gensim` allows us to use [callbacks](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html) for such purposes.

Example:

```
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

class MonitorCallback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    def __init__(self, test_words):
        self._test_words = test_words

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        print("Model loss:", model.get_latest_training_loss())  # print loss
        for word in self._test_words:  # show wv logic changes
            print(model.wv.most_similar(word))

"""
prepare datasets etc.
... 
...
"""

monitor = MonitorCallback(["word", "I", "less"])  # monitor with demo words
model = Word2Vec(sentences = trainset, 
             iter = 5, # epoch
             min_count = 10, 
             size = 150, 
             workers = 4, 
             sg = 1, 
             hs = 1, 
             negative = 0, 
             window = 9999, 
             callbacks=[monitor])
```

- now there's some [issues](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjQg4zzm5PgAhUqpIsKHTcqBHUQFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FRaRe-Technologies%2Fgensim%2Fissues%2F1172&usg=AOvVaw1f0_kOzCBG1EupM1GkAUPM) with `get_latest_training_loss` - may be it's incorrect (bad luck, for now github is down, can't check). I've tested this code and loss increases - looks weird.
- may be you prefer `logging` - gensim is [fitted](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) for it.

Comment: @Thank you! It's exactly what I needed. However, like you said, the loss increases and the word vectors don't even change, though it's another issue. I'm guessing it can be because of my data as I'm not really using _words_ or _sentences_ but rather items as indices. I will work on it.

Comment: Glad to hear it works! Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721503/gensim-word2vec-on-predefined-dictionary-and-word-indices-data) helps with a new issue.

Comment: The running-loss-tally doesn't make total sense in current gensim versions (through at least 3.7.0) - it resets only each time `train()` is called, not each epoch. See this thread for more info about how to interpret the delta-in-loss (per epoch/callback), and other caveats against over-intepreting the loss: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/ZcxHCuPzksE/g7gUH5p4AgAJ

Comment: @gojomo Thanks! That was pretty explanatory. So I stopped trying to get the loss each time as it does not really make sense much apparently.